# TensorFlow freezes the screen when I kill its execution

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

Whenever I kill running TF code, my entire screen freezes and becomes unusable. By kill I mean either pressing `Ctrl+C` in terminal or closing the IPython tab in Spyder.

I've tried using `Ctrl + Alt + F1` but nothing happens. However, if I am listening to music it continues to play without any effect.

I've noticed some of the times that this happens during the execution of `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. However it can happen during training too. How do I go about exactly diagnosing this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I posted as an issue on github but no solution. I reverted back to an older version of the nvidia driver as a workaround for now